# Why does the code work for all the images, except for the first one?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I'm working on a memory game. I want to display images of cards in two rows. All cards are displayed correctly, except for the 1st one in the second row. running this code requires using CodeSkulptor. The entire program is here:
http://www.codeskulptor.org/#user41_a22429Vx58_2.py

```
def draw(canvas):
    global deck, cards, WIDTH, HEIGHT
    num_start = 10
    w = 67
    h = 100
    center_source = [w // 2, h // 2]
    center_dest = [w // 2, h // 2]
    for c in deck:
        for card in cards:
            if card == c:
                if center_dest[0] <= WIDTH:
                    canvas.draw_image(cards[card], (center_source), (w , h), (center_dest), (w, h))
                    center_dest[0] += w + 2
                elif center_dest[0] > WIDTH:
                    center_dest = [w // 2, h // 2 + h]
                    canvas.draw_image(cards[card], (center_source), (w , h), (center_dest), (w, h *2))
                    center_dest[0] += w + 2
```

Comment: the link is not working

Comment: `if card == c:` why?

Comment: @njzk2 because the list **deck** is shuffled. the cards need to be at different positions every time the player starts the game. card is a key in the dictionary.

Comment: but if card and c are the same, why do you even iterate on `cards`? why not just use `c`?

Comment: @njzk2 because **cards** is a dict in which I store names of the images, whereas **deck** is a list, in which I only store numbers. Of course, I suppose I could just put names of the cards in the list instead of numbers... Thanks!

Comment: I meant that `cards[card]` is exactly the same as `cards[c]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your elif condition only triggers 1 time when `center_dest` needs to reset its horizontal position. This is when `canvas.draw_image(cards[card], (center_source), (w , h), (center_dest), (w, h *2))` gets called where the `h * 2` causes the improper draw.

If you remove the `*2` it will work. You could also restructure the logic as follows so you are not duplicating the draw:

```
if center_dest[0] > WIDTH:
    center_dest = [w // 2, h // 2 + h]
canvas.draw_image(cards[card], (center_source), (w , h), (center_dest), (w, h))
center_dest[0] += w + 2
```

To make it extensible to an arbitrary number of rows change the update to:

```
if center_dest[0] > WIDTH:
    center_dest[0] = w // 2
    center_dest[1] += h
```

Comment: Thanks so much @Sean McMillan